# What's the word or phrase for "reading strategy/orientation"?

Tags: american-english, reading

In English, we read from left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

In traditional Japanese, text is read up-todown, right-to-left.

Is there an English word that describes the "reading strategy" of a particular culture or language? Printers can be configured with "page orientation" for either "Portrait" or "Landscape", so perhaps something like "*reading orientation*"?

---

#### tl;dr

The accepted answer, plus Java's concept of [text directionality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getDirectionality(char)) inspires me to believe **directionality** is the most appropriate word here.

Comment: They're not technically reading strategies but writing|printing strategies. And don't forget *boustrophedon*.

Comment: I would suggest refraining from selecting a correct answer within only a few hours. You might get better answers if it takes days.

Comment: Yes, the directionality of a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's right-to-left, it's called *dextrosinistral* text, and when left-to-right, *sinistrodextral*. These names are based on a default orientation of left-to-right, but in English, that is true.

Comment: Thanks @Carl Smith (+1) - but is there a word that encapsulates both these terms (and perhaps others)? For instance, in computer science, there are first-in-first-out (FIFO) structures called *queues*, and there are first-in-last-out (FILO) structures called *stacks*, however both queues and stacks are called "*data structures*". So, according to you, we have *dextrosinistral text*, and *sinistrodextral text*, but what are both of these text types instances of? **Text orientation, perhaps?**

Comment: Again, I'm looking for the word that *describes* these reading strategies, not the names of the strategies themselves!

Comment: There's no name for all forms, as that is just *text*. Text always has a direction, so you'd have no distinction for text that just has a direction.

Comment: I understand what you mean though: Is there a term for the directions of text, like *orientation*.

Comment: Exactly: I think the answer here is either "*text direction*" or "*text orientation*". Which one is more accurate?

Comment: I'd go with *direction* or *flow*, but maybe someone can offer a better answer. I do get what you're asking, and realise my answer doesn't really provide what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks again @Carl Smith - I see Java has a concept of [*text direcgtionality*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getDirectionality(char)), and accept that as good an answer as any.

Answer (score 0):

In [CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) there is a property called 'writing-mode' which dictates exactly this concept and it can have values such as: rl-tb, tb-lr, lr-tb, bt-lr, bt-rl, etc.

Although I would expect that if you were to ask somebody "what writing-mode does English use," they'd ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You would say the "text direction", like "I changed the Hebrew page's text direction to RTL."

Along with text, the general layout of a webpage may be said to be "RTL" or having a direction of right to left, and would generally be referred to as the page's "direction."

"Directionality" would not be used in American English, they would just say "the page direction" or "the direction of the page."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).